# Importing FBX triangulates

Tags: import

I downloaded this old 3DS max file for a dog, then exported it from Max as an FBX using the settings you see in the image on the left. I imported it to Blender with the settings you see on the right and it triangulated the mesh. I looked at another answer that said to uncheck triangulate and preserve edge orientation on the Blender import but there are no such options. I tried checking and unchecking multiple items and reimporting it to the same triangulated result. I have also tried exporting and importing as a DAE but that did not work. Unsure what do try next.

[image]

Any suggestions? For a way to import as quads only or detriangulate.

Comment: FYI: FBX imports are always triangulated, no matter what settings you put in the exporter or in the importer, no matter what 3D software. The reason for this is that both OpenGL and DirectX are triangulating the mesh anyway, because any 3D hardware is going to convert any kind of polygon into triangles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender has an ability inside edit mode to convert triangles to quads. Press ALT + J with everything selected, or by selecting everything, CTRL + F for Face Menu, then Tris to Quads.

Edit: Something that might take you the rest of the way there is the [Quadriflow Remesh](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/retopology.html#remeshing) tool. Its available in Blender 2.81+. As with all things unknown, I'd test it on a safe duplicate.

Comment: Thats awesome I never knew those options were there. It removed most of the quad but there are still quite a bit there. Will those need to be removed manually or is there another way to reduce those?

Comment: @LuckyCOINNNN - that depends solely on the purpose of your mesh. Gotta tell us something.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just change the FBX exporter with these settings and it works with 2.83
Make sure you DO NOT select "split per vextex normals" this will double up vertices on import!

[image]